# Android WebView - how to load online pictures from local HTML (email content)

Tags: android, email, webview

I'm developing a simple email client in Javamail. I'm getting a HTML email contents, and load them using:

```
mWebView.loadData(html, "text/html",  "ISO-8859-2");
```

pictures from email source won't load because they are not local (they aren't even online direct links).
sample img from email source (spam/commercial type message with pictures):

```
<img src="cid:18697_DesignPBCfinal_u35_PL_03.gif" alt="kliknij tutaj" style="display: block;" border="0">
```

Is there an easy way to load those pictures?